# python filter function with arguments

Tags: python, filterfunction

Lets say I've a list of ScriptMetadata object

```
class ScriptMetadata:
  id = 1
  script_name = "test"
  script_run_start_time = 1
  script_run_end_time = 3
  ..
  ..
```

I want to provide an API like below

```
class ScriptInfoParser:
    def get_filtered_data(filter_func):
      [I've logic here to obtain a uber list of ScriptMetadata]
      # apply the user supplied filter func on this uber list and return result
      result = filter(filter_func, all_metadata_list)
      return list(result)
```

If I want to provide a filter func such that give me the ScriptMetadata objects for which script_name is "foo" I can have

```
    def get_foo_runs(script_metadata):
        if script_metadata.script_name == "foo":
            return script_metadata
print(ScriptInfoParser.get_filtered_data(get_foo_runs))
```

Question is how can I parameterize the filter func so that I can have one function that can take parameters dynamically and apply filtering

```
get_script_runs(script_name):
  <?? magic filter func>
  return ScriptInfoParser.get_filtered_data(magic_filter_func) # returns scriptmetadata list that matches script_name
```

Also I wanna go complicated i.e more than one param e.g give me scriptmetadata items for script_name="foo" and script_run_end_time < 2 etc etc

Any help appreciated

Comment: One potential way is to create a "template" object that starts out with all values being `None`.  You then set the values you want to match and call a `find_matching` function that compares the fields that aren't `None`.

Comment: Class methods should have a `self` parameter, unless they're static methods.

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about:  https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/34f9bfb49c0a59eb5518b8677cf42763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very open ended question, and there are many ways of accomplishing this. One of the most readable ways to filter on various attributes might be to pass lambdas into a combining function.

```
filter_funcs = [
lambda script_metadata: script_metadata.script_name == "foo",
lambda script_metadata: script_metadata.script_run_end_time < 2
]
def apply_filters(script_metadata, filter_funcs):
    for filter_func in filter_funcs:
        if not filter_func(script_metadata):
            return False
    return True
```

You could also keep the inputs shorter by using eval.

```
filter_strs = [
"script_name == 'foo'",
"script_run_end_time < 2",
]
def apply_filters(script_metadata, *args):
    for filter_str in args:
        if not eval(f"script_metadata.{filter_str}"):
            return False
    return True

apply_filters(script_metadata,
              "script_name =='foo'",
              "script_run_end_time < 2")
apply_filters(script_metadata, *filter_strs)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kdas/Documents/work/testkdas.py", line 12, in <module>
    res = ScriptInfoParser. get_filtered_data(apply_filters(filter_funcs))
TypeError: apply_filters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filter_funcs'
  ]

    def apply_filters(script_metadata, filter_funcs):
        for filter_func in filter_funcs:
            if not filter_func(script_metadata):
                return False
        return True

Comment: apply_filters() as it is written above takes a script_metadata and the filters as arguments. You could use it using filter() by binding arguments like this: filter(lambda script_metadata: apply_filters(script_metadata, filter_funcs), metadata_objects)